# Find Stream size before performing other operations

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream

In my program, I repeatedly<sup>1</sup> [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) Java 8 [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to reduce a collection of objects to a single one. The size of this collection can vary a lot throughout the execution: from 3 objects to hundreds.

```
public void findInterestingFoo(Stream<Foo> foos) {
    internalState.update(foos.collect(customCollector()));
}
```

In the process of optimizing my code and searching for bottlenecks, I made the stream [parallel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) at some point. This worked at that point in time, as the collections were all fairly big. Later, after changing other parts and parameters of the program, the collections became smaller. I realized that *not* making the stream parallel was more efficient. This makes sense: the overhead of distributing work over multiple threads for 4 objects is simply not worth it. It *is* worth it for hundreds of objects though.

It would be really convenient if I could make only big streams parallel:

```
public void findInterestingFoo(Stream<Foo> foos) {
    if (isSmall(foos)) {
        internalState.update(foos.collect(customCollector()));
    } else {
        internalState.update(foos.parallel().collect(customCollector()));
    }
}
```

Of course, this is possible to do manually when the stream is created from [an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-int-int-), [a collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--), or [manually](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#builder--). That is, we know what elements go in the stream, so this can be tracked. I am however interested in solving this in a generic way, so that no matter what kind of stream is passed to `findInterestingFoo`, it is handled appropriately and as efficiently as possible.

Something like [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) might help, except it terminates the stream before I can [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) it.

I am well aware that streams are designed to not have a set size, in particular:

> - Possibly unbounded. While collections have a finite size, streams need not. Short-circuiting operations such as `limit(n)` or `findFirst()` can allow computations on infinite streams to complete in finite time. — [`java.util.stream` package description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Still, I wonder if there is any way to determine how many elements are in a stream *before* performing any operations on it. Does a stream really not know that it is created from a finite collection?

__________
<sub><sup>1</sup> Thousands of times. Optimizing this led to a speedup from about 1.5 to 0.5 seconds total running time in my case.</sub>

Comment: "*Does a stream really not know that it is created from a finite collection?*" - You are talking about an interface, so the answer is: No, a (general) `Stream` does not know whether or not it was created from a (in)finite source since it does neither define a `isFinite()`- nor a `size()`-method.

Comment: How much does performance matter in your case? To me it would sound like for up to a few hundred elements, whether you go parallel or not will make but a tiny difference.

Comment: @Turing85 Sure. But as far as I know, there is no `SizedStream` interface or anything along those lines. Or is there? As far as I can tell, the streams created by say, `Arrays.stream` are just `Stream`s.

Comment: If it *really, really, really* matters, add a parameter and have the caller pass a hint as to whether the stream is big or small (or just expected to be big or small).

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, the problem is that this method is called thousands of times. The difference was going from 1.5 seconds to 0.5 second, in my case.

Comment: @OleV.V. That would work in my case, definitely. "This not possible with the Java 8 `Stream` interface" is a perfectly acceptable answer to my question, I was just hoping that a better way exists :-)

Comment: @Justastudent javadoc normally lists all public classes/intefaces that implement/extend an interface (see, e.g. [the `List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html)). If you look at the [`Stream` interface documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), you can see no sub-interfaces and no implementing classes, so no: there is no `SizedStream` or similar (within the Java API).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In theory, you could do something like this:

```
public void findInterestingFoo(Stream<Foo> foos) {
    Spliterator<Foo> sp = foos.spliterator();
    long size = sp.getExactSizeIfKnown();// returns -1 if not known
          // or sp.estimateSize(); // Long.MAX_VALUE means "unknown"
    internalState.update(
        StreamSupport.stream(sp, size > PARALLEL_THRESHOLD)
                     .collect(customCollector()));
}
```

[`spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#spliterator--) is a terminal operation that consumes the input stream, but you can pass the [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) to [`StreamSupport.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to construct a stream with exactly the same properties. The second parameter already tells whether the stream should be parallel.

In theory.

In practice, the current stream implementation will return different `Spliterator` implementations depending on whether the stream is parallel or not. This implies that recreating the stream as a parallel stream may end up with a stream that is incapable of doing parallel processing when the original stream wasn’t already parallel before calling `spliterator()`.

It does work well, however, if there are no intermediate operations, e.g. when you directly pass in the `Stream` created from a collection or array.

Calling [`parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) before `spliterator()` to get a parallel capable stream that may still run sequentially if you decide to do so, works in a lot of cases. However, if there are stateful intermediate operations like `sorted()` in the input stream, they may get fixed to run in parallel then, even if you do the `collect` sequentially (or vice versa).

---

Another problem is of a fundamental nature. The number of elements doesn’t actually say whether there will be a benefit in parallel processing or not. This does depend on the per-element workload, which does not only depend on your terminal `collect` operation but also on the operations already chained to the stream before entering your method. Even if you conclude that your collector’s workload is already high enough to deserve parallel processing, it might be that the incoming stream has operations like [`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-), [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) or [`distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) (on an ordered stream), which often run *worse* in parallel and would require an entirely different threshold.

A simpler solution is to let the caller decide, as the caller knows something about the size and nature of the stream. You don’t even need to add an option to your method’s signature as the caller can already make the decision by calling `parallel()` or `sequential()` on the stream before passing it to your method, and you can respect that by simply not changing the mode.

Comment: interesting question and answer (I miss a day and feels like an eternety). I do have a follow up question if I may. What if the calling API does not know or cant tell when to use paralle, but *I do*. Is there a way to tell if that Stream is *actually* using skip or distinct, well I guess Disctict flag could be queried. But what about skip or limit for example. I find myself in these situations sometimes, if I could query these flags I could tell parallel or not. Sorry flr the typos if any, on the phone

Comment: @Eugene a `DISTINCT` flag doesn’t tell you that there is an expensive `distinct()` operation in the chain. A stream could be naturally distinct, because the source is a `Set`. Even `IntStream.range(…)` produces distinct values and has perfect parallel performance. Simply said, there is no way to tell. Also, there are other source properties that may affect parallel performance, e.g. just consider that we might stream over the lines of a file. Usually, the main reasons to assume that parallel processing won’t be good lie on the caller side. The other end only knows about *additional* obstacles.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! I took the liberty of making some small changes to it, please feel free to revert anything you don't like. Just a heads up; I plan on awarding a bounty to your answer, because it answered my question and then taught me a thing or two on top of that.